# AJAX load more button not working as i need

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So i am building wordpress plugin and I am trying to add ajax load more button for my custom post type shortcode. But i can't really work it out. It keeps loading same data over and over. This is my shortcode:

```
public function list($atts) {

            $loop_args = array(
                'orderby' => 'post__in date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'post_type' => 'listing',
                'posts_per_page' => $atts['limit'],
            );

           $loop = new WP_Query($loop_args);

            ob_start();
?>
            <div class="listings-wrapper">
                <div class="js-filter container <?php echo $single_cas; ?>">
                    <div class="list-items">
                        <?php

                        while ($loop->have_posts()) :
                            $loop->the_post();
                            include LISTINGS_BASE_DIR . 'templates/shortcodes/list-toplist.php';
                        // End the loop.
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                if ($loop->max_num_pages > 1)
                    echo '<div class="more-posts">Load more</div>';
                ?>

            </div>
        <?php
            // Restore original post
            wp_reset_postdata();

            return ob_get_clean();
        }
}
```

Here i localize ajax script:

```
public function enqueue_scripts()
        {
            // For load more button

            wp_enqueue_script('ajax-loadmore', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'js/myloadmore.js', array('jquery'), $this->version, false);

            wp_localize_script('ajax-loadmore', 'wp_ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));

        }
```

Here is load more function:

```
<?php

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_more_listings_ajax', 'more_listings_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_more_listings_ajax', 'more_listings_ajax');


function more_listings_ajax()
{
    $offset = $_REQUEST["offset"];

    $loop_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'listing',
        'status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'offset' => $offset,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($loop_args);

    while ($loop->have_posts()) :
        $loop->the_post();
        include LISTINGS_BASE_DIR . 'templates/shortcodes/list-toplist.php';
    // End the loop.
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    die();
}
```

And here is my ajax script:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".more-posts").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            offset = 1;
            $.ajax({
                // use the ajax object url
                url: wp_ajax_object.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    action: "more_listings_ajax",
                    offset: offset
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    offset++;
                    $('.list-items').append(data);


                },
                error: function (data) {
                    // test to see what you get back on error
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I am stuck here and any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: You're adding the page count, but you do no pass it to php ajax script. Ajax script does not get and somehow handle the 'page' attribute therefore it gets same post over and over.

Comment: Okay, i did some changes to code but still couldnt make it work. Added offset property but i cant make it so on each ajax call it grabs next post. At the moment offset is 1 and is not increasing. Could you check the code? Thanks

Comment: Move offset = 1; outside of click event. You're resetting it everytime back to 1